# Pundit Scope inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, pundit

I need something like Scope inheritance in pundit. Imagine this scenarion:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope.where(:company => user.companies)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, any policy inherited from `ApplicationPolicy` has a scope and I can use it through `policy_scope`. This is nice because I have few models `belongs_to :company` with exact same scoping rules.

But what if I need another scope for another policy? Ok:

```
class DeviceGroupPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope.joins(:devices).where("devices.company_id in (?)", user.companies.map{|c| c.id}).group("device_groups.title")
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that the only difference in this `Scope` class is in `resolve` method.

How can I reuse the same `Scope` class from `ApplicationPolicy` in other policies without copy-pasting this boilerplate code?

Comment: extend `ApplicationPolicy` class
```
class DeviceGroupPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def resolve
      scope.joins(:devices).where(devices: { company_id: @user.companies).group("device_groups.title")
    end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `resolve` method is declared inside nested `Scope` class, not `ApplicationPolicy` class itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class DeviceGroupPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.joins(:devices).where("devices.company_id in (?)", user.companies.map{|c| c.id}).group("device_groups.title")
    end
  end
end
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes) (the second code snippet), you can inherit the subclass as well.